# Unit Testing How To Fail a Test for Validates Format of URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, unit-testing

I have a model that requires a valid format of a URL.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_format_of :url, :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix

end
```

**BUT BEFORE** implementing the solution I want to write a test that fails. Is this how someone would go about writing a failed test? (Please no Rspec or Shoulda solution trying to stick with basics before going to advanced testing / matcher frameworks.

```
class EventTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

setup do
# These attributes are valid
@event_attributes = { :title => "A title",
                      :url => "http://somedomain.com/images/land.jpg",}
end

test "should not be valid with an INVALID URL" do
    @event = Event.new(@event_attributes.merge(:url => "htp:/domain"))
    assert_no_match(/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix, @event.url, "Not a valid format")   
  end

end
```

Is the `assert_no_match` the right approach. Any suggestions.

Comment: If the focus is on rails I would follow hartl's recommendation to use a combination of rspec (which is more readable imho) and rubular to craft url matching tests. I don't know about TestCase, but you seem to be on the right track, though you might want to try a few more failing examples against the regex.

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to jump into RSpec part of me thinks I need to stick it out and maybe try MiniTest. I don't know I'll checkout that tutorial you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you should be use a regex to validate a URL at all. Use a `before_validation` callback along with `URI.parse` to clean it up (strip out userinfo, add the scheme if it doesn't have one, ...) and then `URI.parse` again for validation to make sure the URL components are what you want them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the right approach, because you're not testing `Event` validation at all. Instead, a common pattern is to create an object with an attribute that will trigger the validation error and assert that the validation exception has been raised. So, in your case:

```
assert_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) do
  @event = Event.create!(@event_attributes.merge(:url => "htp:/domain"))
end
```

Rspec is good, so you should try it at some point, and better sooner than later, I think. Also there is a nice library for the `@event_attributes.merge` pattern you've used: it's called [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). Check it out, it will save you some trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your not the first to tell me to jump to Rspec. I guess I'm trying to do things slowy before jumping ship. Your solution is fine but when I run the test I get the following message `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid expected but nothing was raised.`

Comment: Yes, exactly, if the validation is missing you get an error - a failing test is a sign you should change your code. Now is the time to add the validation.